# Use remote ViM clipboard from iterm2 on Mac OS X

Tags: ssh, vim, osx

I have been using VNC for a long time for development and now I decided to move to `iterm2` and `screen`.

But there is a small problem.

I have to ssh into a remote machine and use vim there.
And I want to enable `set mouse=a` option.
Also I need to be able to use the remote vim clipboard in the ssh session available in the mac applications.

For this, I used [these instructions](http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2012/09/osx-remote-vim-clipboard-sync.html), but they did not help.
I installed x11, selected the needed options in the `preferences->pasteboard` and ssh'ed to the remote machine with `ssh -x akshya@aksh-vm`.

For some reason this does not seem to work. Am I missing some portion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible the remote machine's vim doesn't support the X clipboard/selection registers. If you type `:ver` there, does it say `+clipboard` or `+xterm_clipboard`?

If not, you may have to resort to other means to use a clipboard, such as running [clipper](https://wincent.com/products/clipper) on your Mac, plus always forwarding port 8377, plus adding necessary key bindings to your Vim config files. The Clipper page is sparse but the demo video should tell you what you need to know to use it.